# Are carrots safe to eat after they have turned black?

Tags: food-safety, carrots

I recently got a bag of carrots out of the fridge, and find that most of them had turned black.  What causes this, and are they safe to eat (with or without peeling)?

Comment: This was one interesting question... I wonder if you would buy carrots from market if they were black instead of organge :D (any other colour but [these](http://wyrdy.com/news/wp-content/uploads/carrots_of_many_colors.jpg) )

Comment: I have bought and eaten black carrots before now - but there is a marked difference between carrots that are black and carrots that have turned black

Comment: I definitely meant the latter, "carrots that have turned black". That's why I gave the piture link to make sure to include carrots with all possible colours, including the purple/black ones..

Comment: Apropos black carrot: Vintage carrot and camomile https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FjN546QGSMA

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When carrots turn black, it is almost always caused by rot. I would definitely not eat them.

Comment: Is it not safe to simply cut the rot away?

Comment: @pm_2 if it's just the ends, you might be able to generously cut away the rotted parts, but if it's a lot of them in the bag, I wouldn't take my chances.

Comment: @pm_2 - I'd think that if the carrots were sitting around long enough to rot, even the parts not rotted would at least be significantly worse than before in flavor and texture.  I can get 2 lbs of carrots at the grocery store for about $1.40 USD, 1 lb bag for $.89 USD.  Are you really that hard-up that you have to eat rotten carrots?

Comment: A few people have asked questions like: why not throw them away/why take the chance, etc.  Whether or not I can afford to throw away a bag of carrots, surely we should be trying (as a society) to waste as little as possible.  If we accept that, then it's down to forums such as this to advise on doing that safely.

Answer (score 3):

The carrots are rotten.  I would advise throwing them out.

Answer (score 3):

Please toss them.... black is not good. They should be a bright orange (unless of course of it is the colored varieties, like purple)

Comment: there are carrots that have the black color because of their genes and not from rot so black color alone does not mean rot.

Comment: Were carrots not originally purple? http://mentalfloss.com/article/12388/carrots-were-originally-purple